# JasperSoft Studio 6.0.3 criação de uma tabela em que cada celula é um query

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper

Boas!

Eu sou novo por estas bandas como também a usar este programa Jaspersoft Studio.

Então o problema que estou a ter é que preciso de preencher uma tabela com um tamanho fixo mas onde cada célula tem um query especifico.

Exemplo:
Tabela com as colunas A, B e C e linhas E, F, G. Então para todas as combinações de linha/coluna preciso de executar um query diferente.

Alguém me consegue ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia, olha o pouco que trabalhei com crosstable e table no jasper, 
uso a versão 5.6 ele funciona da mesma forma que as lists, charts e subreports. 
Para o uso você cria uma query para o item (list, chart, subreport, crosstable ou table), 
não sei se vai te ajudar, mais você pode criar um objeto auxiliar e instanciar vários objetos cada qual com o nome e o conteúdo da sua linha/coluna. 
Normalmente para objetos complexos, que usa de dados de vários objetos, trabalho assim. Dúvidas estamos aê! Abraço!